# Why is the new seam not effecting the UV map?

Tags: texturing, uv

I'm in the process of texturing this ship I downloaded and I am trying to unwrap it. For some reason the UV map will not change when I create a new seam. Is this some kind of bug, or am I missing something?

Thanks

[image: UV problem]

Comment: You are unwrapping it after you create the new seams, right?

Comment: You'd probably need to re-unwrap that part.

Comment: Yup! Pretty weird eh?

Comment: Looking closer at the UV map, it doesn’t appear to correspond much to the ship at all.

Comment: It is kind of strange.

Comment: Is it possible to reset the UV's and try again? I suggest saving your work first though just in case it doesn't work. So save then reset UV's then unwrap again.

Comment: Yeah you're right, I'm trying to get it cleaned up but it's pretty difficult.

Comment: @Jovial Brit I gave that a try but it's still not showing up. Thanks though.